# CakePHP: uses parent model while calling parent::function()?

Tags: php, cakephp

In `CatsController` I called a parent's function

```
 parent:index();
```

In this function, the parent controller (`AnimalsController`) uses its own model `Animal`:

```
public function index() {
$this->set('articles', $this->Animal->find('all'));
}
```

So when I called `parent:index()` in `CatsController` I will get an error as `CatsController` will use its own model `Cat` instead of the parent's model `Animal`:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object
```

Rather than loading the model using `::loadModel`

```
Controller::loadModel('Article');
```

How can I solve this problem? What is the best way to "bind" the parent's model to the child?

Comment: Do you extend -> class Animal extends AppModel ?

Comment: @Dezigo You mean in the `Cat` model file? Yes.

Comment: Try to import it: App::import('Controller', 'Animals')

Comment: @Dezigo I did that at the very start. And it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### $uses

Either put `Animal` in the [$uses](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3a%24uses) array:

```
<?php
App::uses('AnimalController', 'Controller');

CatsController extends AnimalController {

    $uses = array(
        'Cat',
        'Animal'
    );

}
```

### loadModel

Or modify the code to [load the model before using it](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3aloadModel):

```
public function index() {
    $this->loadModel('Animal');
    $this->set('articles', $this->Animal->find('all'));
}
```

### ClassRegistry

Or use the class registry:

```
public function index() {
    $Animal = ClassRegistry::init('Animal');
    $this->set('articles', $Animal->find('all'));
}
```